# Change attribute with jQuery, based on another div's css

Tags: jquery, css, button

The below function does what it needs to - it checks if the div `#searchBar` is shown (it's a popup search box), and updates the `placeholder` attribute of `#QuickSearchQuery` accordingly.

```
<input type="search" name="keywords" placeholder="Search..." title="Search" id="QuickSearchQuery" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() { 
                if($('#searchBar').css('display') == 'block') {
                    $('#QuickSearchQuery').attr('placeholder','Additional Search Options');
                } else {
                    $('#QuickSearchQuery').attr('placeholder','Search...');
                }
            });
</script>
```

The problem is that it only does this when the page loads. `#searchBar`'s display can change from block to none based on the user clicking a different button, and when this is done it doesn't change the `#QuickSearchQuery` attribute.

I can't have the attribute change happen when that button is clicked, unfortunately, because there are other things which can cause `#searchBar`'s display to change (clicking outside of `#searchBar's` div will set it to `'display: none'`).

I don't have a live example because the site isn't live yet, but mostly I just want to know if this kind of thing is possible.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if it is possible too but, you can use `$('selector:visible')` to check if an element is visible.

Comment: Use MutationObservers to watch DOM element attribute changes.

Comment: Create a custom event and trigger that event to show/hide your item. Then handle your logic in an event handler for the custom event.

Answer (score 3):

You have written your logic inside document.ready event which is executed only once when page loads. Place your logic inside a function and call it on button click.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't call it on click because it is based on the #searchBar's display of either 'block' or 'none'. I could bind the attribute changing to the same click that opens #searchBar, but when you click outside of #searchBar it closes the div (changes it to display: none), but it wouldn't change the attribute. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: I am not sure why this answer was voted up so much. The original question clearly stated placing it in the button click was not an option and explained reasons why. To me this answer only shows lack of reading or understanding the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The change of an attribute like this is a [DOM Mutation event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents)

You can monitor them using this [Mutation events plugin](https://github.com/jollytoad/jquery.mutation-events)

But to be honest @Akshey Bhat has the simplest solution - channel all your logic through one function if you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MutationObservers to watch DOM elements for changes. Below is an example of watching attribute changes. This is for pure javascript. I am not sure if jQuery has anything like this built in.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/e6c1xdob/

HTML:

```
<div id="some-id" data-test="somevalue"></div>
```

JS:

```
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        alert(mutation.type);
    });
});

var conf = {
    attributes: true,
    childList: false,
    characterData: false
}

observer.observe(target, conf);

target.setAttribute('data-test', 'newvalue');
```

Here is an example of watching the searchBar for only style attribute changes. Whenever the style attribute changes lets check if the display changed and update accordingly. This code will work if you are applying display changes inline. If not and are using classes to make these changes you can change this code to watch the class attribute instead to see if a specific class has been applied.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var searchBar = $('#searchBar')[0];
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            updateAttribute();
        });
    });

    var conf = {
        attributes: true,
        childList: false,
        characterData: false,
        attributeFilter: ['style']
    }

    observer.observe(searchBar, conf);
});

function updateAttribute() {
    if ($('#searchBar').css('display') == 'block') {
        $('#QuickSearchQuery').attr('placeholder', 'Additional Search Options');
    } else {
        $('#QuickSearchQuery').attr('placeholder', 'Search...');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logic written inside document.ready event which execute only when page loads. SO you have also write logic for button click.

Here is some logic that you can use.

```
<input type="search" name="keywords" placeholder="Search..." title="Search" id="QuickSearchQuery" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() { 
                if($('#searchBar').css('display') == 'block') {
                    $('#QuickSearchQuery').attr('placeholder','Additional Search Options');
                } else {
                    $('#QuickSearchQuery').attr('placeholder','Search...');
                }

            });


                $('button').click(function() { 
                    if($('#searchBar').css('display') == 'block') {
                    $('#QuickSearchQuery').attr('placeholder','Additional Search Options');
                } else {
                    $('#QuickSearchQuery').attr('placeholder','Search...');
                }
               });
</script>
```

Comment: The original question stated putting it in button click was not an option and detailed reasons why.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this is to define a custom event that can be triggered whenever you possibly need to update the behavior of your element. This way, you can trigger the event on document load, and whenever other elements change, and consolidate all your logic in the custom event handler.

Here's a sample where I trigger the `myToggle` event on document ready and when a `toggleSearch` button is clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#searchBar").trigger("myToggle");
});

$("#toggleSearch").click(function() {
  $("#searchBar").toggle();
  $("#searchBar").trigger("myToggle");
});

$("#searchBar").on("myToggle", function() {
  if($('#searchBar').is(':visible')) {
    $('#QuickSearchQuery').prop('placeholder','Additional Search Options');
  } else {
    $('#QuickSearchQuery').prop('placeholder','Search...');
  }
});
```

```css
#searchBar {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="searchBar">
  Search Bar
</div>
<input type="search" name="keywords" placeholder="Search..." title="Search" id="QuickSearchQuery" /> 
<input type="button" id="toggleSearch" value="Toggle Advanced Search" />
```